# Losing projection Infomation in standalone PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

I'm new to PyQGIS and I have been stuck with this for quite some time. I'm trying to run processing script in standalone PyQGIS. My script is working fine and giving the result that I want when running it in Python Console of QGIS 3.16.3 (Hannover) (Ubuntu), but when I run it as a standalone script in Python 3, the result is weird. I noticed that my processing result will loss its projection information.

For example, this line of script below to project my SHP file to Sinusoidal projection will work fine in QGIS Python Console, but when running it as stand alone script, the result's projection will be undefined and the output geometry will remain as input (unprojected/undefined CRS):

```
processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {'INPUT':'/home/input.shp','TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:54008'),'OUTPUT':'/home/output.shp'})
{'OUTPUT': '/home/output.shp'}
```

This is also happening with other processing/algorithm. The output will gives undefined projection result.

Can some one point me where I might be doing something wrong?

Note: Below is the full script that I run in as standalone Python 3 in case there is something that causing this problem:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python')
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing')

from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/share/qgis/", True)
qgis = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.initQgis()


from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {'INPUT':'/home/input.shp','TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:54008'),'OUTPUT':'/home/output.shp'})
{'OUTPUT': '/home/output.shp'}
```

Comment: Change 'EPSG:54008' to 'ESRI:54008'. There is no EPSG crs with 54008 numbered.

Comment: @Xi Jin, thanks for your comment. When I run the same script in QGIS python console, it works as I expected and EPSG:54008 is recognized by QGIS. I think this behavior occur when the script run in standalone environment and  it has nothing to do with the target CRS. When I tried to run different processing/algorithm with different CRS (for example fixgeometries operation, input file in WGS84) the output's CRS will become unrecognized/missing.

Comment: I tried the code(as you write above) but it didn't work for me. I mean it wasn't as expected. Output layer has no crs. As I said, if you change EPSG to ESRI, it will work. You can search this "epsg : 54008" in google to see that there is a epsg crs with 54008 or not. https://epsg.io/54008